GridSearchCV performs worse than baseline
I'm working on a binary classification problem using scikit-learn. One of the models I've tested is KNeighborsClassifier, for which I've obtained a baseline score ("recall_macro") of 78% using the default parameters. Furthermore
I then run a GridSearchCV crossvalidator (using parameter grids that include the defaults, using only the training set, and targeting the scoring metric I need), but I get an "optimized" score of 71%. Not only that, but the recall for the minority class goes from 59% down to 43%.
I understand that GridSearchCV doesn't run on the exact same data the model is fit on, so there may be slight discrepancies, but this seems excessive. What am I missing?
